# How to format the vaiable output uing printf in a columner way

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have below script which returns the output of the some variables, i am using `printf` to align the output format but i'm not able to make it correctly formatted either `right-justify` or `left-justify`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rsp $'Please Enter password below: ' SSHPASS
echo -n  ""
export SSHPASS

print "\n"
printf "Hostname        CPU     MEM     SWAP"
remote_connect() {
   target_host=$1
        mem=$(sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" free -g | /bin/awk '/^Mem/{print $2}')
        swap=$(sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" free -g | /bin/awk '/^Swap/{print $2}')
        cpu=$(sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" grep -c proc /proc/cpuinfo)
    printf "%-20s %10s %10s %5s\n" "$target_host" "${cpu} ${mem} ${swap}" 
}  2>/dev/null
export -f remote_connect
< /home/cpls/mb_hosts xargs -P5 -n1 -d'\n' bash -c 'remote_connect "$@"' --
```

### Result:

```
Hostname        CPU     MEM     SWAP
cpl1855.ind-blr01.cpl.com  4  2  8
cpltp064.ind-blr01.cpl.com  2  1  8
cpltp065.cdi.eu-cdc01.cpl.com  2  1  8
cpl1856.cdi.de-hbg01.cpl.com  2  2  8
cpl1853.cdi.eu-cdc01.cpl.com  2  1  8
cpl1854.cn-sha01.cpl.com  2  1  8
cpl1983.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com  2  1  8
cpl1984.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com  2  1  8
cpl1986.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com  2  1  8
```

### Expected:

There is a utility shipped with RHEL systems called `column` which is used to columnate lists.

```
$ cat tt | column -t
Hostname                       CPU  MEM  SWAP
cpl1855.ind-blr01.cpl.com      4    2    8
cpltp064.ind-blr01.cpl.com     2    1    8
cpltp065.cdi.eu-cdc01.cpl.com  2    1    8
cpl1856.cdi.de-hbg01.cpl.com   2    2    8
cpl1853.cdi.eu-cdc01.cpl.com   2    1    8
cpl1854.cn-sha01.cpl.com       2    1    8
cpl1983.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com   2    1    8
cpl1984.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com   2    1    8
cpl1986.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com   2    1    8
```

Comment: You know you are piping output to `| column -t`. How do you think `column` works?

Comment: @KamilCuk, sorry i was just trying that but could not get how to fit that, yes it works though but how to fit it here that's i'm missing,   i removed that ..

Comment: ` i removed that` and how's the output?

Comment: @KamilCuk, i Just have edited the POST with `column -t` output in the `Expected` section.

Comment: Two things that jump out: your hostnames are longer than 20 characters, and the printf format has 4 conversion specifiers but you're only giving it 2 arguments.

Comment: Sorry, got it now.

Comment: `"${cpu} ${mem} ${swap}"` is one argument...

Comment: @Shawn, i have changed that as `"${cpu}"  "${mem}"  "${swap}"` to be 3 different assignments now

Comment: Why can't you just use `column -t` in your script?

Comment: After that change, you should just need to make the hostname field wider and it'll look better.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn,  that makes it working, `printf "%-30s %15s %15s %15s\n" "$target_host" "${cpu}" "${mem}" "${swap}"`.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
read -rsp $'Please Enter password below: ' SSHPASS
echo -n  ""
export SSHPASS
```

Why do you read the password masked but then export expose it to the whole session environment?

I'd use an ssh key pair with a restricted commands set.

```sh
        mem=$(sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" free -g | /bin/awk '/^Mem/{print $2}')
        swap=$(sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" free -g | /bin/awk '/^Swap/{print $2}')
        cpu=$(sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" grep -c proc /proc/cpuinfo)
```

- If you want to parse the output of `free -g`, you need to set the locale to `C` with: `LC_ALL=C free -g`, or the awk pattern will fail a match on non-US English locale.
- This needlessly establishes 3 distinct ssh sessions to recover data you could get in one go with:

```sh
  read -r mem swap cpu < <(
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" \
      awk '/^MemTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^SwapTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^processor/{c++};END{print c}' /proc/meminfo /proc/cpuinfo
  )
```

Or even better with only access to `cat`, download the data and parse locally:

```sh
  read -r mem swap cpu < <(
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" \
      cat /proc/meminfo /proc/cpuinfo | 
        awk '/^MemTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^SwapTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^processor/{c++};END{print c}'
  )
```

Your snippet fixed:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rsp $'Please Enter password below: ' SSHPASS

export SSHPASS

printf '\n%-32s %10s %10s %5s\n' 'Hostname' 'CPU' 'MEM' 'SWAP'
remote_connect() {
  target_host=$1
  read -r mem swap cpu < <(
    sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" \
      cat /proc/meminfo /proc/cpuinfo |
      awk '/^MemTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^SwapTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^processor/{c++};END{print c}'
  )
  printf "%-32s %10s %10s %5s\n" "$target_host" "$cpu" "$mem" "$swap"
} 2>/dev/null
export -f remote_connect

< /home/cpls/mb_hosts xargs -P5 -l1 bash -c 'remote_connect "$1"' --
```

Example output:

```sh
Hostname                                CPU        MEM  SWAP
localhost                                 8         24     6
```

Comment: write the password on the Prompt, Secondly i have to print a columnize list with header of the output, How i can modulate that all into the script by going with you suggestion, can you showcase that. +1 .  I do not have freedom to choose `sshkeys` for password-less operation otherwise that would be way easy. I have added `export -n SSHPASS` at the end of the script to UN-export it once the program is over.

Comment: This solution does not works well specially `read -r mem swap cpu` with the ssh call.

Comment: @kulfi. Work well: `target_host=localhost; read -r mem swap cpu < <(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q -t "$target_host" cat /proc/meminfo /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^MemTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^SwapTotal/{printf("%d\t", $2/1000000)};/^processor/{c++};END{print c}'); typeset -p mem swap cpu` → declare -- mem="24" declare -- swap="6" declare -- cpu="8"

Comment: thanks a lot for the time and explanation, but i want three commands to be separately included like  `1- lscpu | awk 'NR==4 {print $2}' and 2-  free -g | awk '/Mem:/{printf $2}' and  3- free -g | awk '/Swap:/{printf $2}'`, can help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your formatting problem (aside from passing the wrong number of arguments originally) is that you are defining less space for your first field than some of its data elements require.

I put the data in a file called `data` (the formatting isn't about how you acquire the field data).

```
$: fmt="%-30s %10s %10s %5s\n"
$: printf "$fmt" Hostname        CPU     MEM     SWAP &&
   while read -r -a dat; do printf "$fmt" "${dat[@]}"; done < data
Hostname                              CPU        MEM  SWAP
cpl1855.ind-blr01.cpl.com               4          2     8
cpltp064.ind-blr01.cpl.com              2          1     8
cpltp065.cdi.eu-cdc01.cpl.com           2          1     8
cpl1856.cdi.de-hbg01.cpl.com            2          2     8
cpl1853.cdi.eu-cdc01.cpl.com            2          1     8
cpl1854.cn-sha01.cpl.com                2          1     8
cpl1983.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com            2          1     8
cpl1984.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com            2          1     8
cpl1986.cdi.am-cdc01.cpl.com            2          1     8
```

As you obviously already demonstrate, you can set minimum field widths and left-justify with a leading dash (`-`): -

```
$: printf "/%-5s/%4s/%3s/%2s/\n" abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz.
/abc  / def/ghi/jkl/
/mno  / pqr/stu/vwx/
/yz.  /    /   /  /
```

The issue was that if your data is wider than the minimum width the full field is printed (the last field), but otherwise it space-pads (the first two fields).

As an aside, you *can* add maximum field widths, at the risk of losing info -

```
$: printf "/%5.5s/%4.4s/%3.3s/%2.2s/\n" abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz.
/  abc/ def/ghi/jk/
/  mno/ pqr/stu/vw/
/  yz./    /   /  /
```

Note that `l` and `x` are lost when the field length truncates them.
That's probably not what you want, though there are times...

Comment: Thanks @Paul for you time and explanation , already +1 for the answer and Suggestions.